# Why am I getting Unauthorized Message when calling MongoDb Function in Shell (Robomongo)

Tags: function, mongodb, appharbor, mongodb-query

I have a simple MongoDb hosted in AppHarbor.com. I successfully connected to it using Robomongo and created a simple collection called 'User' and a function called 'insertUser' using Robomongo. But when I try to call the function in shell I get an "Unauthorized" message. I'm using the free Mongo db account in AppHarbor. Please tell me how to successfully call this function?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems I need to issue the call in the following manner for it to work. Eval doesn't seem to work for some reason though.

```
db.loadServerScripts("system.js");
insertUser('aaa', 'bbb');
```

Answer (score 0):

Robomongo is already creating function name. You need only a call.

For you - calling;

```
insertUser('aaa', 'bbb');
```

function;

```
db.User.insert({"UserName":param1,"Password":param2})
```